# React Native fetch from MongoDB not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, react-native, mern

Got an app connected to my database with some messages i want to fetch and render. i had this working back home but I came here to my girl's mom's house and it's all out of whack; TypeError messages. I'm using the iOS simulator so i feel like there's some sort of issue since i'm making the fetch call while running the app from there. Please take a look and tell me what you think!

```
const express = require("express");
const http = require("http");
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const socket = require("socket.io");
const io = socket(server);

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const Message = require("./models/message");
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// MongoDB connection
mongoose.connect(
  'mongodb+srv://blahblah', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  }).then(() => {
    console.log('Connected to the database!')
  }).catch(() => {
    console.log('Connection failed oh noooooo!')
});

// Parse the request body as JSON
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// GET messages
app.get("http://192.168.0.17:8010/api/messages", (req, res) => {
  Message.find({}).exec((err, messages) => {
    if(err) {
       res.send(err).status(500);
    } else {
       res.send(messages).status(200);
    }
  });
});

// POST messages
app.post('http://192.168.0.17:8010/api/messages', (req, res) => {
  Message.create(req.body).then((message) => {
      res.send(message).status(200);
  }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      res.send(err).status(500);
  });
});

// Socket.io connection
io.on("connection", socket => {
  socket.emit('your id', socket.id);
  socket.on('send message', body => {
      io.emit('message', body)
  })
  console.log("connected")
})

server.listen(8010, () => console.log("server is running on port 8000", server.address()));
```

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, View, Button, FlatList, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import io from 'socket.io-client'

const ChatRoom = () => {

  const [yourID, setYourID] = useState();
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState([]);
  const [username, setUsername] = useState([]);

  const socketRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    socketRef.current = io.connect('/');   
    // Sets your ID on connection
    socketRef.current.on("your id", id => {
      setYourID(id)
      console.log(id)
    })
    console.log("socket connection worked")
    socketRef.current.on("message", (message) => {
    recievedMessage(message);
    console.log(message)
    })
    // Gets the messages from the database and sets my messages with them. Peep the concat.
    fetch("http://192.168.0.17:8010/api/messages", {
      method: "GET"
    }).then((res) => {
      return res.json()
    }).then((resJSON) => {     
      console.log(resJSON)
      setMessages(resJSON.concat())
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
    });
  }, []);

    function recievedMessage(message) {
      setMessages(oldMsgs => [...oldMsgs, message])
    }
      
    function sendMessage(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      // Props on this guy match up with the schema.
      const messageObject = {
          body: message,
          username: username,
          id: yourID
    };
      setMessage("")
      socketRef.current.emit("send message", messageObject);
      // Sends the message to the database on submit. Uses the messageObject
      fetch("http://192.168.0.17:8010/api/messages", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json"
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(messageObject)
      }).then((res) => {
          console.log(res)
          return res.json();
      }).catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
      });
    }

    // function handleChange(e) {
    //   setMessage(e.target.value);
    // }

    // function handleChangeUsername(e) {
    //   setUsername(e.target.value);
    // }

  return (
    //Send down the info, render the chat shit
    <React.Fragment>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {messages.map((message, index) => {
          if (message.id === yourID) {
            return (
              <ScrollView key={index} contentContainerStyle={styles.myRow}>
                <Text style={styles.myMessage}>
                  {message.body}
                </Text>
              </ScrollView>
            )
          }
          return (
            <ScrollView key={index}>
              <Text style={styles.partnerMessage}>
                {message.username}:   {message.body}
              </Text>
            </ScrollView>
            )
          })}
        </View>

            <View>
                <View style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', marginTop: 30 }}>
                    <TextInput
                    value={message} 
                    onChangeText={message => setMessage(message)} 
                    placeholder="Say something..." />
                    <Button title='snd msg' onPress={sendMessage}/>
                </View>
            </View>

            <View>
              <View>
                <TextInput
                    value={username}
                    onChangeText={username => setUsername(username)}
                    placeholder="Your name..." />
              </View>
            </View>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    display: 'flex',
    height: '70%',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    width: '100%',
    marginTop: 100
  },
  myRow: {
    width: '100%',
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    flex: 1
  },
  myMessage: {
    width: '45%',
    textAlign: 'center',
    padding: 10
  },
  partnerMessage: {
    width: '45%',
    height: '70%',
    textAlign: 'center',
    display: 'flex',
    overflow: 'scroll',
    flexGrow: 1,
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    height: '80%'
  }
})

export default ChatRoom;
```

Comment: It works, any idea on the fetch?

Comment: I get a different iP from that website and what my Macbook says, which should i use? Also, should i keep the port attached?

Comment: OK so when i put in the IP from there I get a response from the Router which makes sense, but when i add the port (:8010) i get [TypeError: Network request failed]

Comment: How can I find that? When i put ipconfig getifaddr en0 in terminal I get the same IP the Macbook shows in Networking.

Comment: With both of those I'm getting [TypeError: Network request failed]. Should i restart my app?

Comment: My frontend is runnig on port 8080, is that important?

Comment: gonna sleep now, but you should update the post with the way you're connecting things. The server looks very strange, `"http://192.168.0.17:8010/api/messages"` should be `/api/messages` afaik. So i don't know if ur trying something else or what, Also,  front and back end are in different computers right? but are those in same network? can you access the front end in the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following changes need to be made:

1. In the express server code, remove the "http://192.168.0.17:8010" from all the app's get and post functions.
   So, for example:

```
   app.get("http://192.168.0.17:8010/api/messages", (req, res) => {
```

should be

```
    app.get("/api/messages", (req, res) => {
```

Reason: The "/api/messages" is just an endpoint exposed at whichever IP address (could be 192.168.0.17 or any other IP) where your express application is hosted.

2. In your React Code: you may need to check the IPv4 address on your development machine/ where ever the express app is hosted. On windows you can do this by typing in ipconfig in the command line.

Add that to your fetch request, in the React app

Comment: Thanks you so much! That worked, it sucks when you spend hours Googling a problem you don't even really understand and this cleared up so much.

Answer (score 0):

use axios to request to server
EX:--

```
import axios from "axios"

const instance= axios.create({
    baseURL:"http://localhost:9000/",
});

export default instance 
axios.post('/api/messages',{
   whatever you want to post in json
}).then.....
```

you can also use async await if want